# Remotely Upload contents on Android app

Tags: android, json, xml, parsing

I'd like to pose a question here in this very forum!

I am new to Android development. I know there is the parsing project that helps you parse JSON/XML from a remote server. Is there any other way alternatively?

I mean, I have an app that has some content. And I dont wanna use these methods for updating the contents of it. Any ideas?

Comment: How would json parsing update content? Its pretty unclear where you are talking about. These methods? Which methods?

Comment: HTTPconection at first. Then the getJSON methods. You just have a JSON url on a server that you use for updating the data.

Comment: It still is completely unclear what you want and what kind of help youre after.

Comment: ok. Let's say I have an app that shows a text. This text needs to be different every day. What are you suggesting? Except parsing XML/JSON.

Comment: I would call a doktor when we were in the same room.

Comment: What is so hard for you to understand? Please, this is not YT or Twitter. This is a serious forum. Do not underestimate or disrespect it. Thank you. Goodnight.